# Downloading a list from a website (as a CSV) and parsing it in Java

Tags: java, csv

I am trying to download and parse a CSV file from a link. All of the examples I have come across on Stackoverflow uses links such as `www.website.com/file.csv` with the . and a file extension on the end.

What I am trying to do is use a link such as `https://buildtheearth.net/buildteams/36/users/csv`. This link will directly download an Excel CSV file to your computer. I'm trying to parse it with java but I am assuming I first have to download it, and parse it from my Downloads folder.

I have some code but when I was writing this I did not download it and provide the path to it which I believe is where I went wrong (it is a discord bot so I can't see stacktraces when running). Ideally it would return the first record of the CSV instead of the IOexception string that it currently outputs.

```
private static ArrayList<String> records;

public static String download() {
        String str = "unassigned string";

        try {
            InputStream input = new URL("https://buildtheearth.net/buildteams/36/users/csv").openStream();
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8");
            
            CSVParser parser = new CSVParser(reader, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withDelimiter(','));
            
             for (CSVRecord csvRecord : parser) {
                 records.add(csvRecord.toString());
        
             }  
             parser.close();
             str = records.get(0);    //<----------- first record string
                
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            str = "Malformed URL";
            
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            str = "File Not Found";
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            str = "IO Exception";
        }
        
        return str;
    }
```

Every time the file is downloaded from the link in the code, a date is included in the name so it changes each day. Can anyone suggest a good way to download the file but overwrite the previous download? Or maybe parse it to another file?

Output:
`"IO Exception"`

Expected output:
`The first CSVRecord as a string`

**UPDATE**

It seems that I overlooked discord authentication which may be my problem. As a result, this question is now unrelated to the problem. Thank you to everyone who tried to help. Since posting, an API was released for the website which makes it much easier to pull the information so this question is not relevant anymore.

Comment: hi, are you getting an exception - is the idea to store the data somewhere?

Comment: @IronMan Ultimately, I would store this data in the arraylist of the `CSVRecord.toString()` 's and search through that later. Right now it is giving me an IOException

Comment: I tested your URL and it goes to discord authentication. I believe this is the real issue. You need to make sure you have proper  authentication to access the file/url, before actualy fetching the result...

Comment: @ariefbayu Oh that's right, I believe you need to login with discord in order to get the CSV. Well I guess my question has changed then since I forgot about that. Is there a post you can point me to that deals with authentication?

Comment: *"Is there a post you can point me to that deals with authentication?"*  -  Did you try searching?  Or are you asking someone to do that for you?

Comment: @ariefbayu Im not trying to make people do it for me. My searching just hasnt come up with many useful results. I meant to convey if you already know of a source that can help.

Comment: @Matt err... emm... I'm not the one who said that

Comment: @ariefbayu haha sorry about that m8

Comment: OK, so I think this is how you get the authentication token (in Javascript): https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2.  (Most of the stuff I found is for the Discord Java API ... or wrappers for it.)

Comment: @StephenC I am actually using JDA for the bot (Java Discord API).

Comment: But you are not using it in this code.  And that's the point.  Perhaps you should to see if you could use JDA for this functionality.  (I'm not an expert, and I don't have time to clamber up the learning curve today.)

Comment: You can't just update a question. You need to create new question for that

Answer (score 3):

Some of your mistakes are here:

```
    } catch (IOException e) {
        str = "IO Exception";
    }
```

Mistake #1.  You should not return non-data as data.  It makes it difficult for the caller to *act* on the failure of the download.  Let the exceptions propagate as-is, or wrap them in an unchecked exception.

Mistake #2.  If you do decide to treat this as "normal" (ignoring mistake #1), then you should at least log / report the actual exception and message somewhere, so that you (the developer) can figure out what the problem is.

Right now you don't have (and haven't provided to us) any information to say why the download failed, so we can't advise you on how to fix that aspect of the problem.

---

> It is a discord bot so I can't see stacktraces when running.

You probably don't need the full stacktrace.  But surely there must be some way to get at least the exception name and message?

And there is.  According to the [JDA documentation](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/blob/master/README.md):

> JDA is using SLF4J to log its messages.

so you can use it to to log the exceptions then look for the stacktrace in the logfiles.

Or just call `toString()` on the exception and return it.

Comment: This is using JDA so the only thing the bot is able to send are strings which is why I didnt print the stack trace since it wouldnt be output anywhere. The errors are sent by the bot in a discord channel so they are logged somewhere.

Comment: I have looked at some posts about converting a stack trace to a string but after trying a few methods the traces werent being sent by the bot

Comment: Not sure if you were trying to be condescending with the use of `...`  but thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Not a whiz at JDA or SLF4J just writing the bot in my off time.